# UIButton like a radio button

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I need to create button like a radio button. I try to change color. When I click on one of the buttons, all other buttons turn gray. But they do not change their color to gray.

```
extension UIView {

func setGradientBackground(colorOne: UIColor, colorTwo: UIColor, cornerRadius: CGFloat) {

    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds
    gradientLayer.colors = [colorOne.cgColor, colorTwo.cgColor]
    gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
    gradientLayer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius

    layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 10)
 }
}
    @IBAction func oneButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        oneButton.setGradientBackground(colorOne: UIColor(red: 0, green: 0.52, blue: 1, alpha: 1), colorTwo: UIColor(red: 0, green: 0.39, blue: 0.81, alpha: 1), cornerRadius: oneButton.frame.height/2)
        twoButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.94, green: 0.96, blue: 0.98, alpha: 1)
    }

   @IBAction func twoButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
       oneButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.94, green: 0.96, blue: 0.98, alpha: 1)
       twoButton.setGradientBackground(colorOne: UIColor(red: 0, green: 0.52, blue: 1, alpha: 1), colorTwo: UIColor(red: 0, green: 0.39, blue: 0.81, alpha: 1), cornerRadius: oneButton.frame.height/2)

   }
```

[image]

It looks like this. How to fix it ?
[image]

Comment: What does `setGradientBackground` do? It most likely is the reason this doesn't work, because the code should atleast function.

Comment: @SanderSaelmans I've updated. Look, please

Comment: @SanderSaelmans I've found my mistake.You were right, 
it's because of the `setGradientBackground`

Answer (score 1):

Assign all the button with single action first.

Then put all the buttons you want to perform as a radio group in a single array.

```
let buttonGroup: [UIButton] = [button1, button2, button3]

@IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    buttonGroup.forEach { button in
        if button == sender {
            button.setGradientBackground(colorOne: UIColor(red: 0, green: 0.52, blue: 1, alpha: 1), colorTwo: UIColor(red: 0, green: 0.39, blue: 0.81, alpha: 1), cornerRadius: oneButton.frame.height/2)
        } else {
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.94, green: 0.96, blue: 0.98, alpha: 1)
        }
    }
}
```